# jQuery Flot: how to plot graph on top of background image?

Tags: jquery, flot

How do I plot an graph on top of a background image?

I tried several methods, but nothing works. Argh ;)

With the code below only the images shows up, but no graph. How come? Maybe because the graph is plotted behind the image? I hope I can get some help.

Thanks in advance.

```
var data = [ [ ["overview_track_v2.png", -36627, -72447, 35374, 109983] ] , [ [-36627, 35374 ], [-72447, 109983] ] ];

   var options = {
                series: { images: { show: true } },
                xaxis: { min: -36627, max: 35374 },
                yaxis: { min: -72447, max: 109983 },
                lines: { show: true },
                grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },

            };

            var graph = $.plot.image.loadDataImages(data, options, function () {
                $.plot($("#graphPosition"), data, options);
            });
```

Comment: That's just not what the image plugin does - it is for adding grids to prerendered graphs.  i.e. your image would **be** the graph.  All flot does is add axes.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it is simply to put the image as the background of the DIV that is the Flot placeholder and making sure the grid has no background color.

Comment: this is true, and easy to do. But as an FYI, if you are using other plugins like the ability to save the flot as an image the background isn't included.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the commenter was wrong.  I believe this is what you want:

```
var data = [ 
            [["overview_track_v2.png", -36627, -72447, 35374, 109983]],
            { data: [[-36627, 35374 ], [-72447, 109983]]], 
              images: {show: false}, bars: {show: false}, points: {show: false}}
           ];
```

Or, to make it more clear what's going on:

```
var data = [ 
            { data: [["overview_track_v2.png", -36627, -72447, 35374, 109983]],
              images: {show: true}, bars: {show: false}, points: {show: false}, lines: {show: false}},
            { data: [[-36627, 35374 ], [-72447, 109983]]], 
              images: {show: false}, bars: {show: false}, points: {show: false}, lines: {show: true}}
           ];
```